# How to serve http2 from Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, http2

I'm trying to start a Spring boot server to serve http2 instead of http1.1. The code is [here](https://github.com/liquidMocha/practice). I thought having the settings in my [application.properties](https://github.com/liquidMocha/practice/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties) is enough for the server to start serving traffic with http2 but when I start the server from Intellij on my Windows machine, the server starts fine without any warnings or errors. When I did a `curl -k -sI https://localhost:8443/test`, I'm still getting HTTP/1.1 in the header. Why is my local server not using http2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on hitting my server from Chrome, it seems the server is indeed serving through h2. It is my curl that doesn't support http/2.